# How can I hide a Div when text of a label is empty?

Tags: javascript, php, html

I am trying to hide the 'div' by checking if a label is empty. But Something went wrong. Below is the code I used.

```
<script>
 function myfun(){
     if (document.getElementById('department').innerHTML=='') {
         document.getElementById('departmentdiv').style.display="none";
     }
 }
</script>
<body onload="myfun()">
  <div id="departmentdiv" class="row-fluid">
    <label>DEPARTMENT:</label>
    <label id="department"><?php if (!empty($_POST['department']))echo $_POST['department'];?></label>
  </div>
</body>
```

I am getting the POST[department] value from the a different page and assigned it to the label in this page. I want to show the div only if the value is not null. But, the problem is label doesn't show at all on this page even if its not null. Does anybody can help me out

Comment: it does not create the label or do not create the label content?

Comment: it doesnot show the div at all

Comment: are you getting value in `$_POST['department']`. try `echo $_POST['department'];` outside the div and check if you are getting the value.

Comment: Your code works perfect, see [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/WDkB9/)

Comment: Try using: `document.getElementById('department').innerHTML.split(" ").join("") == "")`. This will remove any unnecessary spaces that might have been introduced by PHP.

Comment: your code is working correct, its totally right, btw, you should `===` for comparison in javascript

Comment: But its not working firefox..!!  @OlafDietsche

Comment: Well, it works in my Firefox. So, the issue is not with the Javascript.

Comment: The code is perfect actually I just made some typing error in the label tag.. Guys thanks for help, Every one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can see in this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/WDkB9/), it does work. The problem must be with the PHP code. You don't need to test with `empty()`, just output the variable. If there might be whitespace in the department, [`trim`](http://www.php.net/manual/function.trim.php) it before outputting

```html
<div id="departmentdiv" class="row-fluid">
    <label>DEPARTMENT:</label>
    <label id="department"><?= trim($_POST['department']); ?></label>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

May be you can try php empty function for validation .check if not empty post department then show :

```
<script>
    function myfun(){
    <?php if (empty($_POST['department'])){?>
        document.getElementById('departmentdiv').style.display="none";
    <?php }?>
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

try something like this,

```
if (document.getElementById('department').innerHTML.length) {
    document.getElementById('departmentdiv').style.display="none";
}
```

if whitespace is causing problem then,

```
 if (document.getElementById('department').innerHTML.trim().length) {
   document.getElementById('departmentdiv').style.display="none";
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `isset()` instead of `empty()` :)

Answer (score 1):

InnerHTML is working fine:

```
 if (document.getElementById('department').innerHTML == '') {
     document.getElementById('departmentdiv').style.display = "none";
 }
```

[Here is working demo](http://jsfiddle.net/JRGZg/2/)